# Hartl Ruby Chapter 8.5 Test Fail

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

At the very end of Chapter 8 of Hartl's Tutorial, we create a sessions_helper_test.rb to test the "remember" branch of current_user. Following the steps, the test should pass as green. However it is failing for me. Without the sessions_helper_test.rb, the rake test passes green. So, this test is actually doing its job and finding a failure but I don't know how to fix it.

My test/integration/users_login_test.rb:

```
require 'test_helper'

class UsersLoginTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest

  def setup
    @user = users(:michael)
  end
  .
  .
  .
  test "login with remembering" do
    log_in_as(@user, remember_me: '1')
    assert_not_nil cookies['remember_token']
  end

  test "login without remembering" do
    log_in_as(@user, remember_me: '0')
    assert_nil cookies['remember_token']
  end
end
```

This is my sessions_helper.rb file:

```
module SessionsHelper

    #Logs in the given user.
    def log_in(user)
        session[:user_id] = user.id
    end

    # Remembers a user in a persistent session
    def remember(user)
        user.remember
        cookies.permanent.signed[:user_id] = user.id
        cookies.permanent[:remember_token] = user.remember_token
    end

    # Returns the user corresponding to the remember token cookie
     def current_user
    if (user_id = session[:user_id])
      @current_user ||= User.find_by(id: user_id)
    elsif (user_id = cookies.signed[:user_id])
      user = User.find_by(id: user_id)
      if user && user.authenticated?(cookies[:remember_token])
        log_in user
        @current_user = user
      end
    end
  end
    # Returns the current logged in user, if any
    def current_user
        @current_user ||= User.find_by(id: session[:user_id])
    end

    # Returns true if the user is logged in, false otherwise
    def logged_in?
        !current_user.nil?
    end

    # Forgets a persistent session
    def forget(user)
        user.forget
        cookies.delete(:user_id)
        cookies.delete(:remember_token)
    end

    # Logs out current user
    def log_out
        forget(current_user)
        session.delete(:user_id)
        @current_user = nil
    end
end
```

This is my sessions_helper_test.rb file:

```
class SessionsHelperTest < ActionView::TestCase

  def setup
    @user = users(:michael)
    remember(@user)
  end

  test "current_user returns right user when session is nil" do
    assert_equal @user, current_user
    assert is_logged_in?
  end

  test "current_user returns nil when remember digest is wrong" do
    @user.update_attribute(:remember_digest, User.digest(User.new_token))
    assert_nil current_user
  end
end
```

My users.yml :

```
michael:
  name: Michael Example
  email: michael@example.com
  password_digest: <%= User.digest('password') %>
```

This is the rake test error:

```
 FAIL["test_current_user_returns_right_user_when_session_is_nil", SessionsHelperTest, 2016-02-05 21:59:13 -0500]
     test_current_user_returns_right_user_when_session_is_nil#SessionsHelperTest (1454727553.68s)
            --- expected
            +++ actual
            @@ -1 +1 @@
            -#<User id: 762146111, name: "Michael Example", email: "michael@example.com", created_at: "2016-02-13 20:35:28", updated_at: "2016-02-13 20:35:29", password_digest: "$2a$04$JFRB.ADooQvb0.aHFkSAhOM/pgh8fcE7RA55U6poRRp...", remember_digest: "$2a$04$waNBmpt9z5WT22jRgffILuSI/ZL3ZQWQwXtWTPf7rIk...">
            +nil
            test/helpers/sessions_helper_test.rb:11:in `block in <class:SessionsHelperTest>'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be a formatting error, and I'm not familiar with the Hartl book, however it appears you've defined `current_user` twice which may be causing your problem here.

Comment: Yup, there it is. Another silly one lol. Thanks for the good eyes.

Comment: Glad I could help! By the way do you think the book would be suitable for someone smart but without programming background?

Comment: Yeah, it's the perfect book for someone like that.

Answer (score -1):

In sessions_helper.rb file there are two `"def current_user"`. 
Worked for me:

```
def current_user?
    @current_user ||= User.find_by(id: session[:user_id])
end
```